# How can a Word document reference another file or document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2003

We are currently in the process of migrating from one server to another and are looking to programmatically step through all Word documents in our user's folders.  We need to be sure any references / hyperlinks pointing to the old server will be updated to the new address.

I understand that hyperlinks and references can point to other documents. Are these the only  two ways?  If not, what other ways can one document point to another document or file?

Comment: hyperlinks and cross-references are the only way to link outside in word. Bookmarks link internally. Other office programs have other tools (data connections, for instance, in excel).

Comment: Within the document properties, a document can be linked to the template from which is was created.

Comment: Great, thanks guys.  Can one of you submit a formal answer so I can go ahead & accept it?  Oh, and also, is this the same case with Powerpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the list of external link types that occur to me right now, including some already mentioned...

1. Link to a template
2. A Hyperlink, either represented by a hyperlink field or a hyperlink
   associated with an object such as an image
3. a link to an OLE Object such as an Excel sheet, either represented
   by a LINK field or (in OOXML) internally via a Relationship record
   in the .docx
4. included "text" files or subsets (e.g. bookmarked text areas),
   linked by INCLUDETEXT fields or possibly internally via a
   Relationship record
5. links to images, either via INCLUDEPICTURE fields or internally via
   a Relationship record
6. link from a Mail Merge Main document to its data source
7. links from Master documents to subdocuments (can't remember how they
   are actually done)
8. (uncommon, I would say) link to a data source from a { DATABASE }
   field
9. (uncommon these days) { RD } fields that "include' other documents
   for creation of tables of content and indexes
10. (uncommon these days unless someone has used VSTO to insert Windows form
     controls) if the document contains any ActiveX controls (typically
     forms controls), they must be present on the target machine
11. any other hardcoded paths used in VBA
12. (uncommon, I would say) A document can potentially have a "hyperlink base" which may affect
     the interpretation of hyperlinks in a document.

(There are predecessors of the INCLUDETEXT and INCLUDEPICTURE fields types, but they are so old that it is extremely unlikely that you will encounter them)

For at least one of these, i.e. (6), if you are going to modify the document using the Word Object model (e.g. in VBA), it's important that you do so before you remove the original link target (i.e. the data source). Otherwise, Word will "forget" the data source before you have a chance to point the document at the new one. If you are only processing OOXML documents via, e.g., the Open XML SDK, that should not be quite such a problem.